# Why can't one use this as generic in ArrayList<this>?

Tags: java

I was wondering why one can't use this as a generic while in a class in Java. For example say we have a `class` `User` and we want to have a `static` `ArrayList` of `User`. Why can't I use it like this:

```
class User{
   private ArrayList<this> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<this>();
}
```

I really wonder why I have to specify `User` as generic and can't refer with `this`.

Comment: Because `this` is an _object_ not a class.

Comment: in your case this is a object of type User ... How can you use the object of a class in the class definition its self ...

Comment: @Aeshang: you can absolutely use a class within its own definition. For example, `private List<User> listOfUsers = new ArrayList<User>();` would be perfectly legitimate in this context.

Comment: I think your question could be rephrased as "why is it not possible to use the current object class as a generic type ? E.g. `ArrayList<getClass()>`. That's because generics are resolved at compile time (and then erased).

Comment: Because you are assuming that `User` and `user` are the same in the following statement - `User user = new User()`.

Comment: @musical_coder please explain how will you write this code in User class itself ...

Comment: Look first in [this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a generic type, you specify it as

```
MainType<T>
```

where `MainType` is a parameterized type, and `T` is the type parameter. But the parameter has to be a type as well: in other words, you have to give it a class. So you see things like

```
List<String>
```

where, notice, `String` is another type.

But `this` is a way of referring to the instance of an object in which the current code is executing.

Think of it like this. A `Dog` might be a *type*; but my dog `Rover` is an *instance* of the type `Dog`. You're trying to give an instance when you should be supplying a type.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is not a type.  It's an instance.

doing this

```
ArrayList<this> foo;
```

is like doing this

```
User someUser = new User();

ArrayList<someUser> foo;
```

Comment: Moreover, this is not necessarily a "User". What would happen if you subclass User?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now understand better how it works. Though I found the answer below a bit better (and checked it as correct answer) I found yours good as well and therefore +1'ed it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, I assume that you didn't mean `ArrayList<this>`, but actually `ArrayList<getClass()>`.

Since generics are only meaningful at compile-time, you cannot reference the class of the current object (which needs a `getClass()` *method call*) as a generic type.
Therefore, you will end up with some kind of redundant declaration. The most trivial one that I can come up with would be to define an abstract class with a generic type referencing the actual implementation. E.g.:

```
abstract class Base<B extends Base> {
    private ArrayList<B> listOfInstances;
}

class Implementation1 extends Base<Implementation1> {}

class Implementation2 extends Base<Implementation2> {}
```

This way, all the code that cares about the actual implementation will be handled generically in the supertype, but the subtypes have to explicitly state themselves as generic types for the `Base` class.

But unfortunately, nothing can stop you from declaring `Implementation2 extends Base<Implementation1>`.

Comment: As a side note, the most suitable example that I can find is the `Comparable<T>` interface: most of the time (if not always), you'll make a class comparable to itself, by specifying: `class C implements Comparable<C>`.